# How can I import a single sql file into pandas?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, automation

I am trying to automate (using pandas/python) some daily analysis from a commercial system in a store I own but the only access I have to the databases of the system is through a .sql file generated daily as a backup that contains several tables of everything (from inventory to selling orders). I'm a real newbie in terms of sql, so is there any easy way to extract those tables I need from this single file into pandas? And if so, how can I select which tables to extract?

Edit1: As requested, here are 2 sample tables within the code that have some of the content that I need. That is A LOT going on inside this file (over 734k lines) including queries and functions needed by the program.   [Table of summaries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JU9Yx.png) [Table of inventory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUPpZ.png).

Comment: https://datatofish.com/sql-to-pandas-dataframe/

Comment: Provide a toy example of the database and the table structure and the table you want to extract. Then people can provide you with proper code to extract that table.

Comment: I've updated the post with more info, thanks!

Comment: @Ricardo, as you can see in my images, the syntax from my tables is different than this example. I'm trying to figure out if I need to adapt something.

Answer (score 1):

Use this python code to convert the sql file to csv format:
https://github.com/yashsmehta/mysqldump-to-csv

Then, use pandas to import the csv, and voila - you have a dataframe.

Comment: You must be joking

Comment: @flywire why? this was a serious answer. it will work.

Comment: @Josh, I'm really interested in this method and I'll give it a try. It may not be the cleanest solution but i need something easy and fast so I can focus on the said automation part. Thank you, i'll update any news

Comment: Because csv is unnecessary. First question comment by @Ricardo shows how to do it directly.